# jQuery Stop .blur() event when clicking "submit" button

Tags: event-handling, focus, jquery, blur

I am building a small landing page with a simple demo e-mail signup form. I want to have the form field open up when focused, and then shrink back down on blur.

However the problem I'm facing is when you click the submit button this instigates the blur function, hiding the button and shrinking the form. I need to find a way to stop the .blur() method only when the user is clicking to focus on the submit button. Is there any good workaround for this?

Would appreciate any help I can get!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It isn't the prettiest solution, but it does work. Try this:

```
$("#submitbtn").mousedown(function() {
    mousedownHappened = true;
});

$("#email").blur(function() {
    if (mousedownHappened) // cancel the blur event
    {
        mousedownHappened = false;
    }
    else // blur event is okay
    {
        $("#email").animate({
            opacity: 0.75,
            width: '-=240px'
        }, 500, function() {
        });

        // hide submit button
        $("#submitbtn").fadeOut(400);
    }
});​
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/cvCJm/)

Comment: Yes it does! Thanks a bunch I appreciate the small workaround. The biggest problem was when you click+hold on the submit button, the fade effect would happen and then the button disappears. But with this example you may click+hold indefinitely and the fade effect is tucked away. again thank you sincerely it's much appreciated!

Answer (score 15):

I know this question is old but the simplest way to do it would be to check event.relatedTarget. The first part of the if statement is to prevent throwing an error if relatedTarget is null (the IF will short circuit because null is equivalent to false and the browser knows that it doesn't have to check the second condition if the first condition is false in an && statement).

So:

```
if(event.relatedTarget && event.relatedTarget.type!="submit"){
     //do your animation 
}
```

Comment: This is excellent thank you so much. I've never used the property for relatedTarget I'll definitely spend some time reading on it.

Comment: Seemed like a great approach, but I ran into a problem with this. Tabbing from the last input to the submit button also prevents the blur handler from running, which I don't want to happen.

Comment: @TimB did you find any solution for that problem, I am facing the same issue

Comment: It's been a long time, but I don't think we ever found a solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

Try this inside .blur handler:

```
if ($(':focus').is('#submitbtn')) { return false; }
```

Answer (score 1):

why not rely on `submit` event instead of `click`? http://jsbin.com/ehujup/5/edit

just couple changes into the html and js

wrap inputs into the `form` and add `required` for email as it obviously suppose to be

```
<form id="form">
 <div id="signup">
   <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="me@email.com" tabindex="1" required="required">
   <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submitbtn" value="Signup" class="submit-btn" tabindex="2">
 </div>
</form>
```

in js, remove handler which listen `#submitbtn`

```
$("#submitbtn").on("click", function(e){
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  $("#signup").fadeOut(220);
});
```

and use instead submit form listerer

```
$("#form").on("submit", function(e){
  $("#signup").fadeOut(220);
  return false;
});
```

you may use [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to make it even better.

Doing this you gain point in terms of validation and the native browser's HTML5 validator will make check email format where it is supported.